# How to specify the kendo schema to use in a div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my View using the kendo grid:

```
<div id="MyGrid"
 data-role="grid"
 data-editable="true"
 data-toolbar='[{ template: kendo.template($("#ToolbarTemplate").html()) }]'
 data-columns='[
                    { field: "Description" },
                    { field: "Value" },
                    { command: [{name: "destroy", template: kendo.template($("#DeleteTemplate").html())}], width: 60}
                ]'
 data-bind="source: MyDataSource">
```

Then in a script section a have:

```
kendo.bind($("#MyGrid"), MyViewModel)
```

Everything is working fine. However, now I'm trying to implement a validation to let the user knows that any of the fields inside the Kendo Grid is required. I saw that it can be done in the schema as follow ([Kendo doc link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing)):

```
schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "ProductID",
                                fields: {
                                    ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                    Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                    UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Is there a way to do the same in the div tag as the rest of the attributes? Does data-schema attribute exist?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the kendo validator initialization part in your code. Please refer the following links for documentation and demo

[Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/validator/overview)

[Kendo Validator demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index)